# chapter numbering does not work

Tags: numbering, chapters, front-matter

I'm currently writing my master thesis. Thereto, I received a template from my professor for the thesis (its my first latex project btw. :(). I tried for hours, to correct an error, but I haven't been able to achieve it. My problem is, that Latex is not numbering the chapter (as shown in the picture below). The numbering should look the following:

1. Test

   1.1 Introduction

   1.2 Background

and so forth.

[image: current situation]

These are all packages and layout settings so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,pdftex]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter{test}

\section{Introduction}

\section{Background}

\end{document}
```

---

```
\frontmatter

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{titlepage}


\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{3.25cm}

\includegraphics[width=3cm]{uni-logo-4c}

\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{flushright}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}

{\large \MOrg 

\MInstitution}\\

\textbf{\large \MGroup}

\textbf{\Large M\,A\,S\,T\,E\,R\,\,\,T\,H\,E\,S\,I\,S}

\end{flushright}

\begin{center}

{\LARGE\bf \MTitle}

{\large \textbf{\MAuthor}}

{\large Supervisor: \MSupervisor}

{\large Innsbruck, \MDate} 

\end{center}

\AddToShipoutPicture{

\put(-55,55){

    \parbox[b]{\paperwidth}{

         \hfill \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{UniWatermark}

      }

   }

}

\end{titlepage} 

\ClearShipoutPicture
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! On its own, that is not much use as it does not include any chapters! Please make your code into a complete, small document which people can compile to reproduce the problem. You should remove packages which are not related to the problem. (Take them out - if the problem remains, leave them out; if the problem resolves, put them back.)

Comment: In addition to cfr's comment: It looks like if you just use `\section{}` commands without the upper level `\chapter`

Comment: i just edited the document according to the requests of cfr, so its good to go now ;) thank you for your help so far

Comment: `\cleardoubleempty` and `\halfparskip` are obsolete commands -- and your code provide chapter numbers, if used

Comment: Christian, you are right. If I open a new tex file and copy all the commands to this new file and compile it, without any content, i receive the correct numbering, but in the original file it doesn't work... so it seams I have to figure it out myself :(

Comment: @blanksheet: Would you mind to send me a copy of your file -- I'll have a look (see my mail address on my profile page). I assume erroneous counter reset

Comment: after trying to erase all unnecessary content, I found the source of error. When I include the template of the titlepage, the problems with the numbering start. But because of my lack of experience, I can't identify the interference code line, but I'll quickly update the thread with the code of the titlepage.

Comment: @blanksheet: I got your mail and found the error: Shall I post your document here and the solution?

Comment: great, nice to hear that. thank you. feel free to do so ;)

Answer (score 4):

The OP used `\frontmatter` in file `titlepage.tex` -- this is not an error, but there is no `\mainmatter` as a follow-up, thereby leading the first chapter to be effectively unnumbered and the chapter counter value to be `0`.

This document shows the wrong usage:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\frontmatter

\chapter{My sophisticated content}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Even more sophisticated content}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\frontmatter

% Some other stuff, i.e. a titlepage
\mainmatter

\chapter{My sophisticated content}


\chapter{Even more sophisticated content}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Damn, as always, one wrong line of code has a huge impact on the whole document. Thank you very very much. I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: @blanksheet: Well one missing line in this case, i.e. `\mainmatter`. I personally never use `\frontmatter` etc.